# Force angular to display IE mode on Chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, internet-explorer

We are using an app which retrieves values from HTML page based on input values (basically when we have `value="XXXX"` in input element).

However, we are experiencing strong difficulties with Chrome & Angular with this app. Using the app in Angular page on IE works fine because Angular will display the input with the tag `value="XXX"`.

But when working with Chrome, Angular displays HTML inputs with `ng-value` and so on, we never have the value tag in input elements, which results in our app not working.

Knowing those elements, is there a way to force IE rendering on Chrome on certain URI?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi @YuZhou, I'm sorry for the late response. I think it can solve my problem but it will not be an acceptable answer for my customer. Their environment is highly secured and I do not think we will have authorization to install this extension on all user computers. I will propose it and keep this question opened for now. If this is accepted on customer side I will mark your answer as accepted. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome extension [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) to display web pages using IE within Chrome. It can create a list of URLs that will automatically open in IE Tab.